# Conditional Probability Problem

Tags: probability

Consider a (hypothetical) state with four cities: $C_i$, $i=1, \cdots, 4$. The probability that a resident of the state lives
in city $C_i$ is $p_i$ (and $\sum_i p_i = 1$). If a resident lives in city $C_i$, the conditional probability that he (or she)
contracts the flu is $q_i$.

What is the probability that any resident of the state (living in any city) contracts the flu?

I approach this by first noting that 
$P(C_i)=p_i$ and $P(F|C_i)=q_i$ where F is the probabilty of contracting the flu. Then using the law of total probability, $P(F)=p_1q_1+p_2q_2+p_3q_3+p_4q_4$.

What is the probability that a state resident lives in city $C_2$, given that he/she contracts the flu?

So, we want to solve for $P(C_2|F)$. By definition, $P(C_2|F)=\frac{P(C_2\bigcap F)}{P(F)}=\frac{P(F|C_2)P(C_2)}{P(F)}=\frac{p_2q_2}{P(F)}$ where $P(F)$ is defined above.

Is this is the correct way of thinking about conditional probability questions?

Comment: You should not kill your own post ... leave it even after it is answered!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! You seemed to have figured it out.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @SalechAlhasov The OP asked if his/her solution was right. The answer is yes. If you look at my answer it is... wait for it...

Comment: @SalechAlhasov It is YES! So, how it is not an answer? If you mean that such answers are often given as comments, that is certainly true. On this occasion I did not feel like it.

Comment: Ok, maybe you're right! Chill! :)

Comment: @SalechAlhasov I am cooler than a side of beef :)

Comment: ...с наступающим новым годом!

Comment: @SalechAlhasov You too, thanks!